# How to remove NaN in large list

Tags: r, list, nan

I'm trying to remove my `NaNs` in a very large list.
Removing `NAs` is quite easy with

```
My.List[!is.na(My.List)]
```

But using

```
My.List[!is.nan(My.List)]
```

is not an implemented method for lists (R-Error).

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: can you add a small example of My.List to your question please as the is.na method may be enough. Ex/ `My.List = as.list(c(NaN, NA, 1:3))` ;
`My.List[!is.na(My.List)]` removes both na and nan. But to remove just nan you could try `My.List[!sapply(My.List, is.nan)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 MyList <- na.omit(My.List)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sapply` to find the `NaN`s

```
> x <- list(1, NaN, 3)
> 
> x[!sapply(x, is.nan)]
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 3
```

Comment: What version of R are you using?

Comment: I'm using R/3.2.2  (2015-08-14) - this because of the University Server.

Comment: What are the elements of your list - do you have a nested list? I think you need to edit (some) of your list into your question - use `dput(mylist)' - to make your problem reproducible